# Retrieving Multi Checkboxes from mysql DB

Tags: php, explode, implode

I can't seem to figure this out.  I have 4 multi checkboxes and store them using implode... then try to grab them with explode to compare.  I need to display form with their values checked so I need to see what they checked and display that box ON by default for admin review.  Doesn't seem like Explode is working as it's storing the string on index 0

**Storing to DB:**

```
$pulled = implode(",",$pulled);
```

**Retrieving from DB**

```
<?php          
$pulled = '{pulled}';   // (expression engine CMS field)
echo "before Explode: $pulled <br>";
  // returns:  before Explode: Tanker,End/Bottom Dump,Flatbed,Van 

$pulled = explode(",",$pulled);      
echo "after Explode: <br>";                                    
var_dump($pulled);
  // returns: after Explode: 
              array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Tanker,End/Bottom Dump,Flatbed,Van" }  


$pos = strpos($pulled[0], 'Tanker');
if ($pos === false) {
   echo "<br><br>The string 'Tanker' was not found in the string '$pulled[0]'";
} else {
   echo "<br>The string 'Tanker' was found in the string '$pulled[0]'";
}
```

Comment: are you sure `$pulled` contains comma separated values before explode ?

Comment: can you show what is stored exactly into DB ?

Comment: this is what's stored in the db:     
Tanker,End/Bottom Dump,Flatbed,Van

(it's Collation is utf8_general_ci, not sure if that matters.  it's a varchar)

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
if ($pulled[0] != 'Tanker') {
   echo "<br><br>The string 'Tanker' was not found in the string '$pulled[0]'";
} else {
   echo "<br>The string 'Tanker' was found in the string '$pulled[0]'";
}
```

because as you see in the result of var_dump, the element 0 of the array is exactly the string you are searching for. So no need to do anything else, just compare it. If this doesn't work, then you are not getting the original string cvorrectly. This code works on my machine:

```
$pulled = 'Tanker,End/Bottom Dump,Flatbed,Van ';
$pulled = explode(",",$pulled);      

if ($pulled[0] != 'Tanker') {
   echo "<br><br>The string 'Tanker' was not found in the string '$pulled[0]'";
} else {
   echo "<br>The string 'Tanker' was found in the string '$pulled[0]'";
}
```

Comment: your code works when I put the physical string in there like that... but once I do $pulled = '{pulled}'; to grab db field from CMS, it's like Explode doesn't work correctly and just puts the entire string in $pulled[0].  $pulled[1] contains nothing.

Comment: Logicaly,  that is because the string is different. Try printing it out to see what it contains. I am sure it is modified

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to look for Tanker in the whole string?

```
$pos = strpos($pulled, 'Tanker');
if ($pos === false) {
   echo "<br><br>The string 'Tanker' was not found in the string '$pulled'";
} else {
   echo "<br>The string 'Tanker' was found in the string '$pulled'";
}
```

Comment: Edga, that still doesn't work for me.  when I echo "0: ".$pulled[0]; it displays on the browser as:  0: Tanker,End/Bottom Dump,Flatbed,Van but yet strpos doesn't find even Tanker in that string.

Comment: it works when I put Maxims line:  $pulled = 'Tanker,End/Bottom Dump,Flatbed,Van ';

Comment: Yes, $pulled can not be an array, so explode() needs to be omitted. Apologies, I should have mention that